# How to reference IdentityDbContext in database project shared across solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I would like to take advantage of the IdentityDbContext that comes out of the box in Visual Studio templates for ASP.NET Core projects. However, I would like my entities and migrations to live in a shared project to be referenced by different components of the solution (Web, API, background services, etc.).

My shared database project was going to be a .NET Standard project, but it looks like I'll have to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`. It feels weird introducing to a Standard project a dependency on a Core assembly that is specifically for ASP.NET. Will that pose any problems?

Comment: That's just the namespace, i.e. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`. It doesn't technically have anything to do with ASP.NET Core, especially for packages like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`. There's no reference to anything in ASP.NET Core in that. It's just building off the namespace for Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt be a problem going that way.. Its a problem if you tried to reference Net Framework libraries within a Net Core project

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit some of Identity classes(IdentityUser) for your Entity objects so you must reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` but I do not recommend   to store Identity classes with other Entity classes related to your business layer.

Identity is about infrastructure of your project. Just store Identity related classes Dbbontext, entity classes and services on the same project that you already store Db access codes thats reference EntityFrameworkCore.

Holding two different projects on solution that reference EntityFrameworkCore just a violation of seperation of concerns not more. If you want to hold 2 different projects just use same versions of EfCore.